# Is there any way to read the response header of the script/image which we are including in src of img tag

Tags: javascript, image, http, header, response

In our application, we need to fire a pixel request, which is script and it needs to be added as src in img tag.

It will be **302 response** where we will get the redirection path in the response header from **Location**.

We need to read that path (Location) and use it our code base for further processing.

I tried **fetch() request**, but the Location header is not exposed from the response header and location also not the expected one(getting the same request as redirection url).

If we add the script in src of img tag then the Location in the response header is holding proper value, but not sure how to read the response header.

```
<img src={scriptUrl} width="1" height="1"/>
```

Comment: You are trying to fetch data from the server, why not the regular way (ajax), and the server will return a proper response with the location that you need

Comment: Thanks, @felixmosh, We don't have control over the server since the service is being provided by the third party. So third-party mentioning us to read Location from img src response header. It will be helpful if we get a solution around that.

Comment: It can be solved with a proxy server, your client will Ajax your proxy server, it will to the weird request server to server, read the location header, and return it to the client.